# AlertDialog theme problems

Tags: android

I'm creating an AlertDialog. If create it like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = AlertDialog.Builder((RelationActivity)getContext());
builder.setMessage("No relations found.");
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        ((RelationActivity)getContext()).finish();
    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

This is the result: http://www.ozze.com.br/1.png

But, if I try to set a theme, like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((RelationActivity)getContext()), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
```

This is the result: http://www.ozze.com.br/2.png

Please, can anyone help me with this issue? It looks like when using a theme, the theme "surrounds" the alert dialog.

Comment: Both lines look the same to me...

Comment: I can see just a different font on the second picture that comes from a theme

Comment: give more detail about what you want exactly

Comment: Sorry, I´ve just edited the first code... I pasted the wrong one. Now my question is ok.

Comment: @Marcin S, it´s not only the font. When setting the theme a white box appears behind the alert dialog.

Comment: @androidqq6, I would like to set the Holo Light Theme for that alert dialog.

Comment: please update images urls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set a different Theme for the alert dialog like Theme.Holo.Light try to use ContextThemeWrapper as used in Dialog.java in android source:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog))
```

Comment: is it ContextThemeWrapper applicable for API 14 ,I  doubt .

Comment: Thanks Marcin! That works! But it works with Theme_Holo, not with Theme_Holo_Light... Is this common?

Comment: @AndroidStack It's available from API 1, and is not deprecated.

Comment: Well, Marcin´s solution worked great! But I guess Theme_Holo_Light works perfect only on API Level 14. As soon as I get done with my current project I´ll run some tests.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I think you are right and Holo.Light is available since API 11 Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices It explains how to use Holo.Light in older devices. Then in ContextThemeWrapper just replace android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog with your own style that parent is Holo.Light something like this: R.style.myCustomDialog.

Answer (score 9):

Here is link of Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384274/2080965)

For quick reference I am posting here 
Theme with v7 library **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog**

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.attr.alertDialogTheme);
```

Theme with constructer for **android.app.AlertDialog**

```
android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT );
```

But as per new documentation
**This constant(AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) was deprecated in API level 23**. Use Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert .

```
 android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert );
```