# How to set the theme of an AlertDialog

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog

How do I set the theme of an alert to one of the standard Android themes? I want to use Holo Dark, since the popup defaults to Holo Light.
My code:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        confirm.setTitle("Confirm");
        confirm.setMessage("Confirm and set delay?");
        confirm.setCancelable(false);
        confirm.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startDelay();
               }
           });
        confirm.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
        confirm.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a pass a theme in the constructor.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder (this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK)
```

Answer (score 8):

Theme with v7 library **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog**

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.attr.alertDialogTheme);
```

Theme with constructer for **android.app.AlertDialog**

```
android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT );
```

But as per new documentation
**This constant(AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) was deprecated in API level 23**. Use Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert .

```
 android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert );
```