# datePicker in android

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I want date picker in which i can select year, month and date. like this,

[image]

But i get date picker like this,

[image]

I want to select year and month but in above date picker i can select only month
This is my code :

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateListener;

edBirthday.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(
                        RegisterActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateListener,
                        year,month,day
                );
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );
                dialog.show();
            }
        } );

        mDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker ,int year ,int month ,int day) {
                month = month + 1;

                Log.d( "onDateSet" , month + "/" + day + "/" + year );
                edBirthday.setText( new StringBuilder().append( day ).append( "-" )
                        .append( month ).append( "-" ).append( year ) );
            }
        };
```

Comment: You may find the following link useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38344035/2641380

Comment: i want date picker not month and year picker @SHS

Comment: You need output like first snap ?

Comment: @Unnati the link has example of day, month and year picker as required like first screen shot. Year selection is optional selectable by user. You can make date object from the returned values.

Comment: You have done correctly, I think you might have to click on year in pop-up

Comment: Did you check the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year

Comment: Actually you can select/change Year in the 2nd Screenshot also(by clicking 2019 in topleft) -"I want to select year and month but in above date picker i can select only month"

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible using custom dialog,

Create lay_calander.xml

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Create Java Class for Your Custom Dialog,

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyDatePickerDialog extends AlertDialog implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private DatePicker mDatePicker;

    protected MyDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    protected MyDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
        init();
    }

    protected MyDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, @Nullable OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        init();
    }


    private void init() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lay_calander, null);
        mDatePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        setView(view);
    }

    public void showDatePicker(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, Calendar defaultDate) {

        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, getContext().getString(android.R.string.ok), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getContext().getString(android.R.string.cancel), this);

        mDateSetListener = listener;

        if (defaultDate == null) {
            defaultDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        }
        int year = defaultDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int monthOfYear = defaultDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = defaultDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);

        show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if (mDateSetListener != null) {
                    // Clearing focus forces the dialog to commit any pending
                    // changes, e.g. typed text in a NumberPicker.
                    mDatePicker.clearFocus();
                    if (mDateSetListener != null) {
                        mDateSetListener.onDateSet(mDatePicker, mDatePicker.getYear(),
                                mDatePicker.getMonth(), mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                cancel();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);
    }
}
```

Call Dialog from your activity,

```
MyDatePickerDialog dialog = new MyDatePickerDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Set Date");
        dialog.showDatePicker(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                //Date select callback
            }
        }, Calendar.getInstance());
```

Your Output looks like,
[image]

Make sure your AppTheme Shoud be Extend AppCompat,
Manifest - android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: when i run and click on edit text to open Dialog it throws error java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.  in MyDatePickerDialog class in showDatePicker() fuction  at show()

Comment: My AppTheme is Extended  AppCompat in Manifest.
    <application
            android:name=".AlsQuickStop"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
           tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

   </application>

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity also activity should be.

Comment: My Activity also extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: There is no error it works perfectly but output is not what i want. It gives the second snap output. @Antonino

Comment: Can you provide me information in which simulator you are tested?

Comment: I am testing in Redmi note 4

Comment: I have attached code kindly check it. Link: https://gofile.io/?c=0fd4sF

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.antonino.datepicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

//import android.icu.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static TextView Output;
    private Button changeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
        changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeDate);

        // Get current date by calendar

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Show current date
        Output.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        // Button listener to show date picker dialog
        changeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // On button click show datepicker dialog
                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

            }

        });
    }

    public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        }
        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            Output.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        }

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selected Date (MM-DD-YYYY): "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If everything works you should see a screen like this:

[image: emulator_output]

---

NOTE: instead of `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog` you can use `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` to get a layout like the one in your screenshot but this last one [has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384274/4092588) starting from API 23

**References** 

1 - [DatePicker tutorial](http://www.androidcoding.in/2016/06/09/android-tutorial-date-picker/) 
2 - some functions called in the tutorial for the `Dialog`s were deprecated, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27225882/4092588) provided a fix based on `DialogFragment`s 
3 - [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)) constructor 
4 - [Holo Light Dialog Theme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style#Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog)

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia ok questions: how are you resolving the Calendar class? you are suggested `import android.icu.util.Calendar;` and `import java.util.Calendar;`. Can you please try with this last one if it's not already your current choice? also: which Android phone and Android version are you using for testing? I'm asking because the screenshot I showed in my answer comes from a real test on the emulator [Nexus 5X, API 26]

Comment: My device is MI Note 4. Android version 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia I tried on a Galaxy Nexus, API 23 [Android 6.0] and the output was as the one you were asking for. Unfortunately I don't have the same phone you are using but for what I just said it might be a problem related to the brand. Have you tried running this same app on different phones too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SpinnerDatePicker library here https://github.com/drawers/SpinnerDatePicker
and the usage is very simple as described in its intro.

```
 new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
            .context(MainActivity.this)
            .callback(MainActivity.this)
            .spinnerTheme(R.style.NumberPickerStyle)
            .showTitle(true)
            .showDaySpinner(true)
            .defaultDate(2017, 0, 1)
            .maxDate(2020, 0, 1)
            .minDate(2000, 0, 1)
            .build()
            .show();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

in your view xml file

if you want the clear button to be added, you can build a custom view and set actions for bottom buttons

Answer (score 0):

In android, we have Date Picker Dialog to pick the date but if you want to change the style of the date picker dialog then you can change the theme of the date picker. these are some Themes you can change according to your needs.

```
1.AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK

2.AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT

3.AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK

4.AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT

5.AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL
```

I'm sharing with you the link where you can find more about Date Picker Dialog with source code.

https://www.android-examples.com/change-datepickerdialog-theme-in-android-using-dialogfragment/