# What theme does the Xamarin designer for Mono for Android use?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

When using the designer for Mono for Android in Visual Studio,
the controls have a nice clean design but as soon as you run the app on a device (emulator or real)
the controls have a completely different style:

[image]

Is this because the designer uses a specific theme, if so which one,
or is there something else I have to do to get the same style on the device as in the designer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have the default theme set to Theme.Holo.Light in the designer. In the upper-right of the designer, you will see a button that allows you to select the theme. See the screenshot below.

[image: Mono for Android Theme Selector]

If you need to change the theme to Holo light or just Holo, reference this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices). You will need to make some themes resources and update your application manifest.

Comment: This really helped, I now realize the designer was set to using Theme.Holo by default while my Activity by default took another Theme

Answer (score 2):

This normally happens when your Target Framework is set to Automatic - it will drop down the lowest theme it can use, you will want to change that to API 14/15 to pick up the "Halo" theme from within Android

Comment: It's not my problem exactly but it does help, +1

Comment: heh, thanks for the +1 anyway :) Mike's answer was much better!