# android- apply holographic theme to my app

Tags: java, android, themes, look-and-feel, android-holo-everywhere

I want to make an app that always works with holographic theme(not important on which version of android). is it possible to apply Holographic them to my app on android version below 3.x ?

Comment: You probably can, if you create a custom theme, which is based on the holographic theme, but you should also import the Android Compaibility Libraries. Even so, this does not guarantee you the expected result, but that's the only thing which i have in mind as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the rules you can do this to maintain the theme of your app and the theme of the  phone:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681744/628447

Other posibility is use this incredible page to make all your views
http://android-holo-colors.com/
(take a look of the main page http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html and all of the tools)

And the best solution is use this library:
https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't support Holo below v3 but there is this third party lib that does add it and is widely used.

[HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)