# Change Dialog Theme for every Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes, android-alertdialog

Im using Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar but I dont really like the Light Dialogs/AlertDialogs.

I want to change every Dialog to the dark Holo Dialog.

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:background">#9933CC</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">#02FA07</item>
</style>

<style name="Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Thats what I tried but it has no effect on any Dialogs.

Comment: how did you apply it to your application?

Comment: I tried the same before but never succeeded on the dialogs... I finally added the style dynamically based on the theme selected in the code (for every dialog).

Comment: @YoannHercouet How to set style dynamically for Dialog?

Answer (score 5):

Ok nvm Im stupid its `android:alertDialogTheme` instead of `android:alertDialogStyle`. But this messes up the Preference Dialogs, so I just keep using the Light Dialogs.

Comment: Requires API level 11 :/

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest.xml under the application tag, add this line :

```
android:theme="Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

The issue is that the styles you're changing `android:background` and `android:textColor` are not dialog attributes.

You can see a [full list here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) under `Theme.Holo.Dialog` on line 1617.

The ones you have to change are probably `android:windowBackground` and `textAppearance`

Comment: Yea I did that and it worked for other styles (edited out in my example) but not for the dialog.

Comment: Just using this: `<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"></style>` should give me the dark Dialog right?