# How to change application theme in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-theme, android-appcompat

I want to change the background of Date Picker from white to black, I think it can be done by changing my app theme to holo dark.

Currently it is:
[image] And Iwant to change it  to holo black [image]

So, currently my `styles.xml` in values folder is

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v11 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v14 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Mainifest.xml

```
<application
   .....
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   .......
</application>
```

I am using `appcompat_v7`, so what should I modify my `styles.xml` use Holo Light and Dark Date Picker?

Comment: Are you using HoloEverywhere? If you are not using it, please remove the tag.

Comment: Here you can find a clue to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18839895

Comment: a clue is always frustrating & torment, until & unless it solves ur problem

Comment: what about changing the style of just that screen in the visual layout editor ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt This is possible if we use custom dialog box but making date picker custom  will be a big pain in ass !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting `Theme.AppCompat` as a parent to  themes when the app uses appcompat_v7 solved it !**

*`Theme.AppCompat` is visually the same as Theme.Holo (dark).*

For more information see the Android documentation [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes) for more information !

Answer (score 0):

### ***SOLUTION IS***:: `android:Theme.Holo`

---

Copy this Code and paste it in your `styles.xml` in the `values` folder

`styles.xml` in values folder is

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v11 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v14 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Mainifest.xml

```
<application
   .....
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   .......
</application>
```

---

### - HAVE A LOOK AT --- **[HOLO_EVERYWHERE - PROJECT - CLICK -HERE](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)**

### - HAVE A LOOK AT --- **[DEVELOPER_SITE - CLICK - HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)**

Comment: Thanks, but the app is crashing by `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com...}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: @VivekWarde .... You have to check for other folders, that contain styles files as well, that could possibly override your styles. ... did you do that ?

Comment: wht do u mean by other folders?, BTW the styles.xml are in the folders which I have specified & I have modified all the code according specified by u !

Comment: Sorry, Your answer went me totally wrong, see my answer !

Comment: I was not aware you were using `appcompat_v7` .... My answer was for support `v4` ... and i forgot to ask it ... Glad you were able to resolve it ! Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

OK so **ALL** instances of..

```
    "Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

...need to be changed to...

```
    "Theme.AppCompat"
```

`"Theme.AppCompat"` is the `appcompat`version of `"Theme.Holo"` - the dark version

**You cannot use `"Theme.Holo"` because you are using the `appcompat` library.** They are incompatible. Follow this and it will work!