# TItanium appcelerator : How to create the shape programatically

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator

Is there any way I can create the below image using textfield border in Titanium appcelerator ? I dont want to use the image . Please help .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about views?  Change shape's position and width as necessary.  Efficient?  /shrug

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
// no background color
var shape = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: '300dp',
    width: '200dp'
});

var color = "blue";

var bottom = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: '1',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: color
});

var left = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '1',
    height: '10',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: color
});

var right = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '1',
    height: '10',
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: color
});

shape.add(bottom);
shape.add(left);
shape.add(right);

win.add(shape);

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

This image is showing the line which would appear under android textfield in holo theme. You might wanna have a look at this question [How to use Holo.Light theme, and fall back to 'Light' on pre-honeycomb devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices)