# Can't use Theme.Holo.Light even though I have API set to 14

Tags: android, android-theme

I know this has come up and I looked at some other pages to find some help but I'm still having this problem.

I updated the `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` and hit sync. 
In the manifest file I set the application theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

I still get the `cannot resolve symbol @style/Theme.Holo.Light` error

I can only use the `Theme.AppCompat` stuff, nothing else shows up

Any ideas?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9681744/4385913)

Comment: use @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light instead

Comment: @vs.thaakur you are right

Comment: Hey, thanks, I still can't use android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light" in the manifest file, but I created a new resources .xml, made a custom theme and put parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" and that worked. I'm glad it worked, but is that the only way? Like, I can't do it directly from the manifest file?

Comment: just add @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light in your menifest file

Comment: "@style/Theme.Holo.Light" vs "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" - can you see the difference?

Comment: former refers to your custom style.xml and late refers to androids default styles

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, thanks for the help. I think Android Studio was being a little buggy for me, I noticed that it wouldn't read my device even though it was plugged in, so I just decided to quit out of everything and retry it, and then the code seemed to work (-_____-) I guess it's still relatively new so it's not too unexpected. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can custom your theme and you can set `Holo.Light` over there just create a `theme.xml` file in `/res/values`. And write

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
</style>
```

GO over to `manifest` and set your custom theme.