# Dark background in android app with no explication

Tags: android

Today my app started to have a dark background and only the background, as you see in below screenshots the button or the checkbox have the original beautiful colors. I have tripple checked everything, from gradles to xml's to manifest and style, I have runned the application on 2 devices and I can't figure it out what I can do.

[image: Apk from device]

[image: XML Layout from Android Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the Manifest re the below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

and [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices)

Comment: It worked but can you explain me how the theme changed without doing anything ?